# convertir palabras de mas de 5 letras a lista del siguiente string

Tags: python, string, jupyter

frase = 'Estoy en el curso de python para ciencia de datos'
En python convertir las palabras de mas de 5 letras de frase a lista, solo he podido convertir a lista pero todas las palabras.

```
 frase = 'Estoy en el curso de python para ciencia de datos'
lista=frase.split()
lista
```

Comment: Por favor, mejora el formato de tu pregunta para que se entienda mejor. 1. Forma frases completas y correctas. 2. Pon un ejemplo del resultado concreto que esperas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo lo que preguntas, sería algo como:

```
lista = [palabra for palabra in frase.split() if len(palabra) > 5]
```

1. Dividimos la frase partiendo por los espacios.
2. Nos quedamos solamente con las palabras más largas que 5 letras.

La estructura `[x for ... in ...]` de Python se denomina "list comprehension".